# How to test a function call after state receive value inside expression in React function component using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am looking for the solution for a jest enzyme test case on method call inside expression when it receive state value,

where function call when expression condition get passed, there is no onClick or onChange event fire.

But there is a state which revceive value on Click a button, which pass the expression i.e.:

```
 {(isTableDisplayedFlag && tableData.length && filtersDialog()) || ""}
```

i have already assert the button on click which render a table data.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<componentName{...props} />);
const showPriceBtn = wrapper.find("[data-test='show-pricing-button']");
expect(showPriceBtn.length).toEqual(1);
```

After that, it called a function which set the state value for isTableDisplayedFlag to "True" and
tableData to an array object.

```
 tableData: [
    {cityName: "Bengaluru", discountedPrice: 600000, durationInSecsMax: "180", durationInSecsMin: "1", id: 522, quantity: "1"},
    {cityName: "Bengaluru", discountedPrice: 750000, durationInSecsMax: "300", durationInSecsMin: "181", id: 523, quantity: "1"},
    ]
```

the third one inside expression is an function which in return render a child component RequiredFieldsRenderer as below

```
  const filtersDialog = () => {
    return (
      <RequiredFieldsRenderer
        requiredFields={requiredFields}
        priceNotRequired={true}
        handleSubmit={applyFilters}
        packageAgentType={packageAgentType}
        isFilter={true}
        data-test="filter-dialog"
      />
    );
  };
```

This component - RequiredFieldsRenderer has been imported in test file.
I wrote assertion for this as:
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement()).toEqual(
true
);
But it doesn't give coverage .
Can anyone help into this type of scenario when state update and function render inside expression  ?

````
    const rfr = wrapper.find("[data-test='filter-dialog']");
    expect(rfr.length).toEqual(1);
    ```
Receive : 0
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check post state-updates changes in the wrapper you are testing, ensure the action is done within the test, following which you can update the shallow wrapper which will update the wrapper based on the changed state and then you can write your expect statements to complete the test.

```
// Perform action which updates the state

wrapper.update()

// Write expects to find out what changed in the wrapper
```

Find docs [here](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html)

Comment: It doesn't impact on it, 
still have no coverage as well if i assert with length then it give 0.
```
    expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<RequiredFieldsRenderer />)).toEqual(
      true
    );
    const rfr = wrapper.find("[data-test='filter-dialog']");
    expect(rfr.length).toEqual(1);
```